# Get redirected data with nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, authentication

So I'm using [node-myanimelist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-myanimelist)
npm package which is a wrapper for [myanimelist API](https://myanimelist.net/apiconfig/references/api/v2) and the package uses [pcke-challenge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkce-challenge) which provides a challenge (basically users go to a url, authorize and it redirects the user with an access token for me to use). Here's an image below to clear the idea
[image]

Once you click on allow, the user will be redirected to a URL that you specify with the access token. BUT here's the catch, my application does not have a website and I don't have a place to redirect the user to so what's the best approach to still get the token when the user clicks allow?

**EDIT:**

Here's the code:

```js
const { Mal, Jikan } = require('node-myanimelist');
const auth = Mal.auth(/* app_id */);
const pkceChallenge = require("pkce-challenge");
const pkce = pkceChallenge();

// This is the URL the user gets
const url = auth.getOAuthUrl(pkce.code_challenge);

// "code" here is what clicking allow on the URL above ^ returns with the redirect
const acount = await auth.authorizeWithCode(code,pkce.code_challenge);

// From then on I can do stuff like `account.anime.search(/* stuff */)`
```

Comment: Show your code or welcome the downvotes

Comment: @Pytth - I didn't add the code because it's literally a copy paste from the node-myanimelist npm package that I linked but I get it. My bad.. Here it is regardless